# Joomla - Clicking on site title and changing where it goes

Tags: joomla, content-management-system

I have an issue at the moment, when I click on the site title whilst I'm not logged into the website, it takes me to the log in form, which is what I want. However, when I click it and I am logged in it takes me to just a basic page with a log out button. I would like to change it so that when I click the title and the user is logged in it will take them to a certain page.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What did you do to make the title *not* link to the entire article?

Comment: I think I turned it into a login form rather than a featured article or whatever it's called.

Comment: Then your describing expected bahaviour. Clicking on the *title* of the login page of course brings you to the login page, which is a logout page, when you are logged in.